# Why do we use `wraps` instead of `update_wrapper` as a decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Decorator `functools.wraps` calls method `functools.update_wrapper`.

I want to understand the need to use `wrap` instead of `update_wrapper`.
Why can't we use `update_wrapper` as decorator instead of using `wraps`?

For example:

```
from functools import update_wrapper
def wrap1(func):
    def call_it(*args, **kwargs):
        """wrap func: call_it1"""
        print('before call in call_it1')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return update_wrapper(call_it, func)

@wrap1
def hello1():
    """test hello 1"""
    print('hello world1')

hello1()
```

and

```
def wrap3(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def call_it(*args, **kwargs):
        """wrap func: call_it3"""
        print('before call in call_it3')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return call_it

@wrap3
def hello3():
    """test hello 3"""
    print('hello world3')

hello3()
```

work. But why the following doesn't?

```
def wrap2(func):
    @update_wrapper(wrapped=func) # error, see below
    def call_it(*args, **kwargs):
        """wrap func: call_it2"""
        print('before call in call_it2')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return call_it

@wrap2
def hello2():
    """test hello 2"""
    print('hello world2')

hello2()
```

with error

```
TypeError: update_wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'wrapper'
```

[The declarations of `wraps` and `update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) are:

```
@functools.wraps(wrapped, assigned=WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS, updated=WRAPPER_UPDATES)
```

and

```
functools.update_wrapper(wrapper, wrapped, assigned=WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS, updated=WRAPPER_UPDATES)
```

The positional argument `wrapper` is the first argument to `update_wrapper`, 
so why doesn't the following pick up `call_it` as `wrapper` argument to `update_wrapper`?

```
@update_wrapper(wrapped=func)
def call_it(*args, **kwargs):
```

Is there some way to use `update_wrapper` as a decorator instead of using `wraps`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `@` as a decorator basically boils down to this:

```
 @(value)
 def f(...):
     ...
```

Being the same as:

```
def f(...):
    ...

f = (value)(f)
```

Now if we apply it to your case:

```
@update_wrapper(wrapped=func)
def call_it(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

```
def call_it(*args, **kwargs):
    ...

call_it = update_wrapper(wrapped=func)(call_it)
```

The problem here is that the first time, it is only called with the second argument. It then raises the error immediately.

This is because `update_wrapper` is not designed to be used as a decorator, but `wraps` is a decorator (factory).